# Looping through data from local JSON file to output in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

Here's the sample JSON data

```
{
  "elements" : [{
    "name": "Hydrogen",
    "symbol": "H",
    "number": 1,
    "period": 1,
    "category": "diatomic nonmetal ",
    "atomic_mass": 1.008,
  }]
}
```

Here's the code I've wrote to display data

```
$(function(){

var btn = $('button');
btn.on('click',load);

function load(){
    var fetch = new XMLHttpRequest();

    fetch.open('GET','elements.json',true);
    fetch.onload = function() {
        if(this.status == 200 ) {
            var elem = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var output = '';
            for (var i in elem) {
                output += `
                    <div>
                        <p>Name : ${elem.elements[i].name}</p>
                        <p>Symbol : ${elem.elements[i].symbol}</p>
                        <p>Number : ${elem.elements[i].number}</p>
                    </div> 
                `; 
            }
            $('.data').html(output);
        }
    }
    fetch.send();
}

});
```

Problem -->

I've a problem with for loop or any loop for that matter, w/o loop and inserting value of `i` manually in `elements[i]` works perfectly.

Comment: what is the problem or issue,any wrong output..can you be brief and it isnt valid JSON data.

Comment: Here's what console returns - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: Since your json is invalid,can you put console.log(elem ) after this line var elem = JSON.parse(this.responseText); and post the logged data here.

Comment: It is valid, it's returning the array

Comment: just post your whole elem variable data here.

Comment: There's no problem in that json file, anyway here's the link to that JSON file - https://github.com/Bowserinator/Periodic-Table-JSON/blob/master/PeriodicTableJSON.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `elem` you obtain is not an array, is just an object with one field that contains an array, that's why your loops are failing. You have to loop through `elem.elements`. Try this...

```
fetch.onload = function() {
    if(this.status == 200 ) {
        var elem = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var output = '';
        for (var i=0, l=elem.elements.length; i<l ; i++) {
            output += `
                <div>
                    <p>Name : ${elem.elements[i].name}</p>
                    <p>Symbol : ${elem.elements[i].symbol}</p>
                    <p>Number : ${elem.elements[i].number}</p>
                </div> 
            `; 
        }
        $('.data').html(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried `i < elem.elements.length` how is it different from what you've done?

Comment: It's just a good practice thing I read in the past. With my option, you avoid the system to calculate the length of the object on each iteration (to check the `i<` condition). I use it since then

Comment: Cool, makes sense!